# Slider Revolution Problemas con Firefox

Tags: firefox

Buenos días a todos, da la casualidad que este plugin falla bastante en firefox. Actualmente trabajamos en última versión del plugin y en la última versión del template. 
Pero tenemos un problema con los layer que contienen vídeos. Cuando colocamos una imagen de cover del vídeo, en firefox, deja de funcionar con un comportamiento raro.

Cuando cargas la página y vas a reproducirlo falla, pero si trasladas el focus del ratón a otra ventana, cuando vuelve el focus a Firefox carga perfectamente.

¿ Alguien sufre del mismo problema, o sabe alguna solución ? Gracias.

Comment: Buenas Juan, bienvenido. Deberías poner algo de codigo para ver donde está el fallo u orientarnos un poco heheh Si no, puede ser cerrada por ser *demasiado amplia*

Comment: Yo he usado Slider Revolution en varios sitios hechos en Wordpress y trabajo con Firefox como navegador predeterminado, no he tenido problemas. ¿Puedes explicar con más detalle que es un _comportamiento raro_? ¿Cuando dices que falla que ocurre, no se ven las imágenes, no avanza el slider? Tienes que ser más concreto y si puedes mostrar un ejemplo donde se vea el fallo, mejor.

Comment: Cuando el slider termina de cargar, puedes darle Clic encima y pasa de la imagen de cover al vídeo reproduciéndose, pues en Firefox no pasa eso, simplemente parece que la llamada falla. Pero tras salir de la ventana y volver a entrar, se empieza a reproducir, no se si es que no carga correctamente el JS

Comment: Tendrás que poner un ejemplo donde se vea el error, yo no puedo reproducirlo. Me funcionan bien los sliders en Firefox

Comment: Mañana por la mañana intentare grabar un video gif y lo pendro con lo que sucede exactamente. Gracias de todas formas por la ayuda.

Comment: Un video tampoco sirve, tu explicación es suficiente para entender lo que pasa. El problema es que si no se puede reproducir el error es dificil encontrar una solución porque no se puede saber que está fallando.